# ReferenceError: parseCookies is not defined even i had imported it

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, middleware

#### I am using NextJs and it's serverless functions.

I have a api route `/api/blog/write`, it is a protected route. Only authorize users can access it. For this i defined a middleware which check if request is comeing from a authorize user then processed other wise redirect request to login page.

#### api/blog/write.js

```js
import requiredLogin from "@middleware/required-login";
const index= (req, res) => {
  const cookies = parseCookies({req}).ts
  res.statusCode = 200
  return res.json({ status: 'Your first blog' })
}
export default requiredLogin(index);
```

#### @middleware/required-login.js

```js
import { parseCookies } from 'nookies';
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
const JWT_KEY = process.env.JWT_KEY;

const requiredLogin = (handler) => (req,res)=>{
    const token = parseCookies({req}).ts;
    jwt.verify(token,JWT_KEY,(err,dev)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(401).redirect("/auth?auth=signin")();
           return handler(req,res);
    })
}

module.exports = requiredLogin;
```

Using the above code for ***required-login.js*** gives me

***status code*** : 500 and error is `ReferenceError: parseCookies is not defined`. 
When i just replace `return handler(req,res);` in ***required-login.js*** with `return res.status(200).send(dev)` then i am getting expected result.

### error consoled by node is

```js
ReferenceError: parseCookies is not defined
    at index (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\.next\server\pages\api.js:110:19)        
    at C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\.next\server\pages\api.js:151:12
    at C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12      
    at getSecret (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\.next\server\pages\api.js:148:25
    at apiResolver (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\api-utils.js:8:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:45:397)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\dev\bdevg\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:37:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseCookies` is not defined in **api/blog/write.js**, and you use it there.

Since Node.JS (and JavaScript itself) doesn't expose variables defined in one file to another file that has be "`require`d" by that file, you cannot access `parseCookies` in **api/blog/write.js**.

You must import it there as well.

```js
// You must import `parseCookies`!
import { parseCookies } from 'nookies';
import requiredLogin from "@middleware/required-login";

const index= (req, res) => {
  // You use parseCookies on the following line,
  // so you have to import it.
  const cookies = parseCookies({req}).ts
  res.statusCode = 200
  return res.json({ status: 'Your first blog' })
}
export default requiredLogin(index);
```

Comment: I didn't noticed. Thanks